# How to clear out Color of pixel at a point in OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0

I am working on OpenGLES 2.0. When i tap on screen i am getting point i want to remove the color at the tapped point. Which means i want to remove the whatever it is initially has.

```
glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Color, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(LineVertex), &vertices[0].color);
```

I have tried the above line, this will fill the area with the color provided, but i want to remove the color so that i can see the background, like erase the color at the given point.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you should create a texture in GL_RGBA format that covers the window.  Then you can edit the alpha channel of the pixels in the texture at the touch coordinates and then update the texture with glTexImage2d().

Comment: Thanks buddy, so this will remove the color which is already filled in that pixel? it should be like [UIColor clearColor] type.

Comment: This makes the color of the pixel in the texture image transparent.  You must also display that texture onto a triangle pair or quad.